# Optimising equation with 3 or more changable variables

Tags: mathematical-physics, optimization

In order not to bother you with technical details I've laid my therms in plain math. The sets are experimentally obtained mechanical characteristics, and unknowns are some empirical parameters from the analytical expressions. I would like to optimize the equations in regards to my database specimens $\{1 ... n\}$.

So, if I have known values of sets (or vectors) $A = \{A_1, A_2, ... A_n\}$;  $B = \{B_1, B_2, ... B_n\}$ and the same goes for $\{C\}$ and $\{D\}$. If $x$, $y$ and $z$ are the changeable parameters that I would like to calibrate that is, optimize and the equations goes as:

$$xA_i + B_i^y + (A_i / C_i)^Z = D_i~, ~~i\in[1,n]$$

What method of optimization/calibration would you recommend? Some reading material or anything.

I've usually solved equations in 2D or 3D space, which is easy. Also, I've taken a course about optimizations long time ago, and I am somewhat familiar with *minmax*, *swarm methods* and etc. But I've never used it afterwards. I am familiar with Matlab and somewhat with Python.

Comment: Hi barefoot_fiki. Welcome to Phys.SE. Plain math should go to [math.se]

Comment: Can you formulate an objective function?